# Getting all the children (and their children) of a given parent node in a MySQL/MariaDB relational table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tree, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
parent, child
0 2
0 8
2 3
2 6
3 4
3 5
6 7
6 9
9 10
```

I'm looking for a query to select the sub-tree of a given parent, i.e. If the given parent is "6", the output must be: {10,9,7,6}

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries, which is ideally what you might use for this sort of problem.  How many levels deep can the tree be, and is that max depth fixed?

Comment: it is not depth fixed, but I think no more than 6 levels of depth. Sad to hear that MySQL don't support recursive queries D:!

Comment: You can do a self join 5 times if that be acceptable to you.

Comment: can I make the recursive in PHP or something?

Comment: Of course, recursive queries from PHP are no problem. With a fixed max len, you can do it as well in columns.

Comment: Consider using CTEs of MariaDB 10.2 or MySQL 8.0.x

Comment: @RickJames sounds good, can you show me how to do a MariaDB's CTE for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chek this. The value which specified in @pv := '6' should be set to the id of the parent that you want to find all the descendants of it.

also you can check live [Demo updated](http://rextester.com/PPW46751)

```
            select  Parent, concat ( "{" ,Parent,",",GROUP_CONCAT(concat (child )SEPARATOR ','),"}")   as Child
            from    (select * from #TableName
                     order by parent, child) s,
                    (select @pv := '6') initialisation
            where   find_in_set(parent, @pv) > 0
            and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', child);
```

> Output : {6,7,9,10}

For display childs with parent into one column use below query :

```
            select parent as child from tchilds where parent = @pv2
            union
            select  Child
            from    (select * from tchilds
                     order by parent, child) s,
                    (select @pv2 := '6') initialisation
            where   find_in_set(parent, @pv2) > 0
            and     @pv2 := concat(@pv2,',', child)
```

> Output

[image]

let us know if you have still any questions or concerns.

Comment: TQ DBA @BerndBuffen

Comment: Thanks, I voted up your answer, but I really need not a concat output, a only one column that output that numbers, can you edit your answer please, so I can test on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale could you?

Comment: @alessadro  answer updated and also check updated demo link for all queries.  still any concern contact me sujayb7@gmail

Comment: Thank you very much for your professional feedback ;)

Comment: Hi, How can I Add Child Count, column in the above solution.  @Mr.Bhosale

Comment: how can I get the level of hierarchy in each row as well?