# Getting all the children (and their children) of a given parent node in a MySQL relational table

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I have a table like this:

```
child:      parent:
0003        0003
20010       0003
15003       0003
20013       20013
1234        20013
0003        20013
```

I am looking for a query to select the sub-tree of a given parent including the level of each child, i.e. if the given parent is "20013", the output must be:

```
child: level:
 [1234, 1]
 [0003, 1]
 [20010, 2]
 [15003, 2]
```

**Important detail I can not use cte query so I would be happy for a solution with a standard query**

Attaches the code in NODEJS that brings me the result I need to perform this operation only in the mysql procedure:

```
async function getCldLvl(DB, item, sons, level = 0, treetype) {
    level++;
    let ele1;
    if (treetype)
        ele1 = await myq(`use ??; SELECT * FROM trees WHERE TreeType=? AND ParentKey=?;`, [DB, treetype, item]);
    else
        ele1 = await myq(`use ??; SELECT * FROM trees WHERE ParentKey=? AND ItemKey!=ParentKey;`, [DB, item]);
    const elements = ele1[1];
    if (elements.length != 0) {
        let p = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
            const e = elements[index];
            if (e.ItemKey != e.ParentKey) {
                sons.values.push({"ItemKey":e.ItemKey, "Quantity":e.Quantity, "Level":level});
                p.push(getCldLvl(DB, e.ItemKey, sons, level, e.TreeType));
            }
        }
        await Promise.all(p);
    }
}


let sons = { values: [] };
await getCldLvl(DB, "apple", sons);
console.log(sons);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot use cte query"?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: A recursive cte _is the standard_ here.

Comment: version: 5.7.3, And I can not update the version!

Comment: There is no sql way to resolve this query without using recursive cte

Comment: Sure there is no way? I found it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113828/getting-all-the-children-and-their-children-of-a-given-parent-node-in-a-mysql/67585071#67585071) but there is no child level here :(

Comment: No, there is no way. Unless you know the maximum recursion and create a static query. If you want it dynamic, you need a recursive cte (or a stored procedure). Sorry to give you the bad news.

Comment: Okay, and if I know the recursion is limited to level 10 how can I resolve this?

Comment: The task may be solve when: option 1 - there exists max depth to be retrieved; option 2 - iterative stored procedure is used instead of single query. Option 2 recommended.

Comment: Ok,
I would love to code ...
Thanks :)

Comment: (0003-0003) and (20013-20013) are root rows? if so why (0003-20013) exists?

Comment: Yes,
They are root lines.0003-20013
This indicates that "0003" is a son of "20013" .Only in my table do I define each father as a root even he himself is also a son

Comment: *Yes, They are root lines.0003-20013 This indicates that "0003" is a son of "20013"* ??? if somebody is a child then he cannot be a root. Your data seems to be either inconsistent or illogical.

Comment: Yes this is the form of writing my table,
Every parent is a root even if he is a son.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_childs ()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE get_childs_tmp(id INT UNIQUE, level INT) ENGINE = Memory;
INSERT INTO get_childs_tmp SELECT child, 0 FROM test WHERE child = parent;
REPEAT
    INSERT IGNORE INTO get_childs_tmp
    SELECT test.child, get_childs_tmp.level + 1
    FROM get_childs_tmp
    JOIN test ON test.parent = get_childs_tmp.id;
UNTIL !ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
SELECT * FROM get_childs_tmp WHERE level > 0;
DROP TABLE get_childs_tmp;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c5933bfa05414cd68c91c318a727ed6f

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with the data I put here for example and it is the result not as I wanted https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a4c7315a5ba3951f4ece577b528f8d67

Comment: I edited my question, I would be happy to help.

Comment: @semicolon NodeJS question is separate question - so create new topic. Refer to this one if needed.

Comment: The question is not in nodejs I just attached the code that brings me the result I need in the mysql procedure